# Trying to use array method "fold" on a Future<List> to get total price of items

Tags: list, asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

In Dart/Flutter I am building a model where I get all products prom a remote endpoint using a Future and async await.

When I have retrieved the list I want to specify a property that returns the total amount of all item using the "fold" method of Dart lists.

Something like this:

```
Future<List<Product>> get items async => // here i get products
  await Future.wait(_itemIds.map((id) => api.getProduct(id))); 

Future<int> get totalPrice async => // here i calculate products total amount
  await items.then((iii) => iii.fold(0, (total, current) async { 
        return total + current.price;
  })
);
```

But I get an error:

> The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'FutureOr'. Try 
>    defining the operator '+'.dart(undefined_operator).

How am I supposed to solve this problem in an async language?

Thank you

Comment: Dart compiler still returns the same error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'Product'.
Try defining the operator '+'.dart(undefined_operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `await` doesn't apply to `items` but on all the expression `items.then(...`.

The following code should work:

```
Future<List<Product>> get items async => // here i get products
  await Future.wait(_itemIds.map((id) => api.getProduct(id))); 

Future<int> get totalPrice async { // here i calculate products total amount
  final products = await items;
  return products.fold<int>(0, (total, current) => total + current.price);
};
```

Comment: You can also do `return (await items).fold(0, (total, current) => total + current.price);`. I usually do this to avoid creating another variable.

Comment: Thank you, but both still return the same compiler error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'FutureOr<int>'.
Try defining the operator '+'.

Comment: Code updated. I think the issue comes from bad inference of fold type parameter in this async function.

Comment: Yes, casting the fold method solve the problem. Thank you